# Is there a way to not have unittest.mock raise an exception if it is returned by a side-effect?

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-3.7

I am trying to mock out the methods from the library python-arango.  Specifically, the one I'm having difficulty with is the update_many method:
https://python-driver-for-arangodb.readthedocs.io/en/master/specs.html#arango.collection.StandardCollection.update_many

This method returns a list of items and/or error instances if any of the items failed to update.

So, in my test, I've mocked everything up to the update_many call, and I've set a side_effect for that call to return a generator that yields one item which is a DocumentUpdateError created like so:

```
    mock = MagicMock()
    mock.__class__ = DocumentUpdateError
    mock.error_code = DOCUMENT_NOT_FOUND
    mock.request.data = [request_data]
    return mock
```

This all works, but my problem is that when unittest.mock calls the side_effect, it automatically tests the result with the _is_exception(result) method (unittest/mock.py line 1074) and then throws the result instead of just returning it.  Worse, because this is actually a mock object rather than a true error, Python throws a type error:

> TypeError: exceptions must derive from BaseException

Comment: What, exactly, did you set the `side_effect` to? A generator? A function that returns a generator? A mock DocumentUpdateError?

Comment: Your wording is confusing and self-contradictory. `unittest.mock` won't raise an exception returned by a `side_effect`.